# How to run multiple onEdit functions

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have two onEdit functions that work individually, but I cannot seem to combine them properly to run at the same time.

My goals is to timestamp the cell in column 9 AND copy the whole row to a new sheet when the checkbox is checked in column 1.

I have followed the advice posted elsewhere on Stackoverflow regarding triggers, renaming the functions, etc, but at most I can only get the first function to run.

```
function onEdit(e) {

var colToWatch = 1, colToStamp = 9;
var valueToWatch = "TRUE"; 
if (e.range.columnStart === colToWatch && (e.value === valueToWatch || 
typeof e.value == 'object'))
e.source.getActiveSheet()
    .getRange(e.range.rowStart, colToStamp)
    .setValue(typeof e.value === 'object' ? null : new Date());
}

function onEdit(event) {
// assumes source data in sheet named Active
// target sheet of move to named Found 
// test column with yes/no is col 1 or A
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

if(s.getName() == "Jessica" && r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() == true) {
var row = r.getRow();
var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Done");
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
}

}
```

I expected both functions to run, but I fear I've taken too many disparate pieces of advice, and now neither function runs on edit.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have two functions sharing the same name, and therefore will encounter issues trying to have two separate `onEdit()` functions. Rewrite your script so that you have a single function; and also give a read through the guide on [triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)

Answer (score 0):

In the timestamp function, you are using two undefined properties of [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range): `e.range.columnStart` and `e.range.rowStart`.  Your code works when you replace them with `e.range.getColumn()` and `e.range.getRow()`.

I suggest renaming the functions to describe their function, and then make a new `onEdit` that calls these functions in the correct order.

Here is a working example:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  timestamp(e);
  copyRow(e);
}

function timestamp(e) {
  var colToWatch = 1, colToStamp = 9;
  var valueToWatch = "TRUE"; 
  if (e.range.getColumn() === colToWatch &&
     (e.value === valueToWatch || typeof e.value == 'object')) {
    e.source.getActiveSheet()
      .getRange(e.range.getRow(), colToStamp)
      .setValue(typeof e.value === 'object' ? null : new Date());
  }
}

function copyRow(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named Active
  // target sheet of move to named Found 
  // test column with yes/no is col 1 or A
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if (s.getName() == "Jessica" &&
      r.getColumn() == 1 &&
      r.getValue() == true) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Done");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your responses, DWMORRIN and @sinaraheneba. I had tried something similar, but I think I'm still missing something. DWMORRIN, I tried the code with the edits you suggested, but I'm still only getting the timestamp function to run. Not sure why the copyrow function is not running. Here is an example spreadsheet so you can see what I mean: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eR1weM17nU_RuYyGz8BPo7lk_MRBScMtvmOqviQTvsM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @A.Cummings - I took a look at your link and you had two small bugs: 1 was that you did not fully rename all the `event` bindings to `e` in the `copyRow` function, and the second was that there was some random data way down in the "Done" sheet, so when `copyRow` did succeed, it was copying to a row in the 900 region (due to `getLastRow()` seeing the last row as being 900 something).

Comment: Thank you so much!